# How can I resolve vex-react-template-admin template default application

Tags: reactjs, vuex

I want to use calendar application but I cannot resolve some directories that maps to pages and redux store

### Error

```
./src/redux/reducers/rootReducer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@src/views/apps/calendar/store/reducer' in '/Volumes/D/Innoways/Coding/calendar/src/redux/reducers'
```

### what I need todo includes

- Using redux store for calendar application
- Running calendar application from this Template
  I am using [Vuex react-admin template](https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-react-admin-dashboard-template/documentation/docs/getting-started/gitlab-access)

Answer (score 0):

It was path issue yet I solved by changing `@src/views/apps/calendar/store/reducer`to `@src/views/calendar/store/reducer`
so far I can access redux store with no worry